# Workaround for css3 multi-column image bug in webkit?

Tags: html, css, webkit

There's a [known bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25633) in webkit, where it cut's up images that happen to span multiple columns. Firefox gets it right and I don't care about IE as doesn't know how to render multiple columns at all and degrades gracefully to one big column instead.

Does anyone know of any decent workarounds for this issue that doesn't involve banning images in columns?

Comment: ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Don't think I did, sorry. I haven't looked at this problem for some time either, so not sure what current support looks like.

Comment: haha thanks, nothing's changed...

Answer (score 0):

Try [style="position: relative"] on the affected image/s.

Comment: While keeping the images from getting clipped, your solution also makes their position go haywire. In fact, elements with relative positioning in columns in webkit doesn't work as expected at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and an old school solotion to it.

I added a couple of:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

at the end of the Text and could change the "fold" to my favor. Not nice, bit it works